# Scrapy How I get a random image by a random generate

Tags: scrapy

Well, I have a API application using scrapy and I need pick in html for a form a random image (captcha) for use bypass, but my image is generate by a comum url using method get like this:

[www.examplerandom.com/image](http://www.examplerandom.com/image)

If I collect this normal, a new image is generate.

Is possible in scrapy print like a browser and save this?

Or

exists other solution for my problem.

Comment: If the CAPTCHA is embedded in the HTML (e.g. `data:`), you should be able to extract it without using that URL. If the image is displayed directly from the URL, then it is not in the HTML, which means it is OK to fetch whatever random image the URL sends.

Comment: If I making download of this image, using my browser other image is generate, In my mind the one solution is a print of current image.